# Cannot change TextView visibility inside Java class (android)

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, findviewbyid

I have a class named `DataNode` that will be instantiated inside an `AsyncTask`. Ok then.

But, I wanna show an error if the task fails, or a title if it success.
So, **inside the `DataNode` class** I have a method called `onOk()` that will be called by the Async.

I already have the Title/Errors instantiated in the XML stylesheet file as invisible and just want to show 'em.

I am trying to do (in the title example):

```
public void onOk(){
  TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblRealTime);
  view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

But I receive the error: `Error:(29, 36) error: cannot find symbol method findViewById(int)`

I've already read another topics but none answered my problem.

Comment: if you're calling that method in `doInBackground` maybe you should use `runOnUiThread` method because `doInBackground` is not in the main thread so you can't call `findViewById` .

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onOk(){
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
          public void run() {
              TextView view = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lblRealTime);
              view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
          }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `DataNode` is neither an `Activity`, nor a `Fragment`, so there's no wonder it doesn't have `findViewById()` method defined. One way to implement your use case is to pass the `TextView` to `DataNode` when creating it:

```
class DataNode {

  final WeakReference<TextView> textViewRef;

  DataNode(TextView textView) {
    this.textViewRef = new WeakReference<>(textView);
  }
}
```

then, use the `TextView` in `onOk()`:

```
public void onOk(){
  TextView textView = textViewRef.get();
  if (textView != null) {
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  }
}
```